# Tree identification - pink buds and numerous fluffy stamen flowers

Tags: identification, trees

This is a tree growing in a friend's backyard, located in the Bay Area, Northern California, USA. (I'm not implying that the tree is native!)

Its flowers have numerous fluffy stamens which are cream in colour, and there are pink flower buds. (The buds look very similar to a eucalyptus).

There seems to be a parasitic infection on some (warped) leaves.

[image: Flowers]
[image: Flowers, Leaves, Buds]
[image: Warped leaves]
[image: Trunk]
[image: Full Tree Canopy]

Comment: Thanks! Good though of adding the bit about possibly being not native. Still, it gives the readers an idea of the climate the tree thrives in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just wondering if the 'pink buds' you describe are actually the fruits, which turn pink/red rather than flower buds. Certainly the only object I can see which is pink appears to be a fruit or seedcase rather than a flowerbud, but it's a little out of focus. If so, this might be *Syzygium jambos*, common name rose apple or malabar plum, though these names may also be applied to similar plants - images of flowers and fruits and a little foliage here https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Syzygium_jambos

Comment: Yes, Syzygium does seem a better fit given bark characteristics and smaller groups of flowers. [Worldagroforestry](http://old.worldagroforestry.org/treedb/AFTPDFS/Syzygium_jambos.pdf) indicates that it does not produce fruit in extremes of range as in SF so the pink may be just coloration in buds due to the insect giving the tree a busy time.

Comment: I did some more Google picture searches for Syzygium jambos, including the trunk, and it seems to match perfectly. https://www.pinterest.ca/amp/explore/syzygium-jambos/  Thanks.

Comment: @ColinBeckingham -- From your document link - "generally a tree reaching 7.5-12 m in height" -- that's certainly the case for this tree...

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a white bottlebrush tree, a Callistemon or Melaleuca, but which one is hard to say, there are many species and varieties. To confirm this, look over the tree for long ranks of the white flowers arranged along the twigs like a kitchen bottlebrush. The white colour narrows the search quite a bit. The bubbly leaves you see are probably a Psyllid infestation, which can happen on bottlebrush trees; they typically damage foliage leaving lumps and bumps.

Comment: Thanks, interesting. I didn't notice any of the flowers arranged in a typical bottle-brush style, à la https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melaleuca#/media/File:Melaleuca_squarrosa.jpg. I (mistakenly?) thought that bottlebrushes usually have a paper-bark type trunk [http://malcolmtattersall.com.au/wp/2018/03/bottlebrush-callistemon-melaleuca/]. (Sidenote: I'm originally from Australia)

Answer (score 1):

The pink fruit looks like syzygium (or acmena). commonly all called lillipilly.
From middle east coast of Australia.